# Tangent bundle on a complex manifold

Tags: complex-analysis, manifolds

When defining the tangent bundle of a $n$-dimensional manifold $M$  whose coordinate-change mappings are holomorphic, do I need to specify where M is immersed? That is, I must assume that $M\subset\mathbb{C}^k$, $k>n$, so that the tangent bundle
$$
TM:=\left\{ (p,v)\in M\times\mathbb{C}^k | p\in M, v\in T_pM\right\}
$$

I know that this is so in the real case (that is, when $M$ is a $n$-dimensional real manifold); is there any change in the complex case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, not in the complex case and not in the real case, either. A manifold's tangent bundle is a well-defined object independent of any possible embedding of the manifold into another space (though an embedding into a vector space does *induce* a tangent bundle).

The definition of the tangent bundle you quoted also doesn't involve any embedding, in fact it could read $(p,v) \in M \times \mathbb{C}^n$ there: the tangent space has the dimension of the manifold, not a bigger one like you might need for embedding the manifold.

Comment: But I can see $(p,v)\in M\times\mathbb{C}^k$ if I denote $T_pM$ as a  vectorsubspace of $\mathbb{C}^k$ instead of as a $n$-dimensional vector space, right? Aren't both definitions equivalent?

Comment: Yes, indeed – the intuitive definition of the tangent space as the embedding space's sub-vectorspace that's, well... _tangent_ to $M$ as a submanifold is of course still valid. It's just not necessary and IMO a rather roundabout way to think about tangent spaces. Also, it's actually misleading: there is no meaningful relation between absolute points in the embedding space and absolute points in any of the tangent spaces, only a differential relation.

Comment: I got it. Thank you; do you think I should edit my question having this in mind?

Comment: Depends... if you now notice you really meant something different with your question, you should perhaps rather post a new one, since this question is useful on its own right (even though my answer is probably a bit trivial).

Comment: I'll leave it as it is, then.

Comment: Is the tangent respectively the cotangent bundle of a complex analytic manifold assumed to be holomorphic or smooth?

Comment: @FlaviusAetius a good question to which I don't know the answer. (I don't actually know much about complex manifolds.)